# Need to know when, and how many times a variable gets updated in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my Tensorflow project, I need to know whether `train_op` as defined below, updates a certain variable or not, and if it does then, how many times it gets updated.

For a feed-forward network this is trivial, one `train_op` call results in one time update of the variable, but in case of Recurrent net, one `train_op` will result in `num_steps` [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent#truncated_backpropagation) updates, but since I have my own variables in the recurrent layer, I am not sure if they are getting updated `num_steps` times or just once.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.InteractiveSession()
__N = 10
tf_w0 = tf.get_variable(name="w0",\
                   initializer=tf.constant(value=10.00,shape=[__N]),
                   dtype=tf.float32,\
                   trainable=True)

tf_counter = tf.get_variable(name="counter",\
                   initializer=tf.constant(value=0.0,shape=[]),
                   dtype=tf.float32,\
                   trainable=False)

loss = tf.square(tf_w0)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
grads_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=loss, var_list=tf.trainable_variables()) 

train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_vars)
```

How can I attach a counter to a variable, such that each time `train_op` updates, it should also increment the counter? 
That way I will know if my variables in recurrent layer (I have my own modified recurrent layer from the original [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) and the code is a bit messy) of Tensorflow are getting updated like the way they should.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the recurrent weights are just updated once. The weights are reused multiple times in the forward pass. Multiple gradients are calculated in the backward pass. Those gradients are added together and then a single update is made.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing what you want, but it is fairly complex. It seems like you have some incorrect assumptions. I will try to clarify some things and hopefully you won't actually need the counter.

In general, variables are updated once per `sess.run(train_op)` call. If your operation is neither inside a [graph function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7cea792897c64a7201c10753866917ed65785db0/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py#L43) (most likely not, this is an advanced concept) nor inside a while loop, it will be executed at most once. If you are using automatic differentiation (e.g. the `optimizer.compute_gradients`) and not adding gradient computing operations yourself, all the gradients will be computed and aggregated before being applied to the variables. The application is done once, unless you call `optimizer.apply_gradients()` multiple times. `apply_gradients` is the function that creates operations that mutate the variables.

This is true even for RNNs. In the case of RNNs, gradient computation is done in a while loop, but once they are computed, they are still applied once - outside of the loop.

If you really want to add a counter. Here is a rough approach you can take:

- Find all the operations in your graph that mutate your variable `v`. These operations would include `AssignVariableOp`, `AssignAddVariableOp`, etc. To do this, you can loop over the graph operations and match on their types and inputs. (The reasoning above basically says that as long as you are using usual TensorFlow idioms, there will be only one such operation).
- Create a variable for your counter `c`.
- For each of the mutation operations you found above, create an `assign_add(c, 1)` operation and add a control dependency from it to the mutation operation. This way, before executing the mutation, TensorFlow will execute the `assign_add` which will increment your counter.